# how can I log the output of the execve call?

Tags: c, logging, execve

I wrote this simple program. I want the output of it to be logged to the test.log as opened below. Is it possible for me to do this?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
      int fd = open("test.log", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY);
      char *path[2];
      path[0] = "/bin/ls";
      path[1] = NULL;

      execve((char *)&path[0], &path, NULL);

      close(fd);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use the pipe operator in your command and pipe either stderr or stdout to file or another pipe, which you can read using a child process. You can pipe the output to pipe that you have created before executing execve and use a child process for reading it.

Comment: You need to make fd 1 (and possibly fd 2, if you also want to catch error output) refer to your file. See `dup2()`.

Comment: Could you please provide an example ? I had been looking into it before, but I couldn't understand the man page very well.

Comment: @CaseyJones: Add `dup2(fd, 1);` before the `execve`. If you want to capture `stderr` as well, also use `dup2(fd, 2)`. Then `close(fd)` *before* the `execve`. Check all error returns. Note that `execve` never returns unless there was an error doing the `exec`.

Comment: Note that if the second argument to `open()` includes `O_CREAT`, the `open()` function requires 3 arguments; the third is the permissions on the file if it is created (as modified by the `umask` setting).  Plausible values for the third argument are 0666 (traditional but not secure) and 0644 (more sensible — don't let other people write to the file).

Answer (score 0):

Working solution, as guided by Rici.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int fd = open("test.log", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0600);
        char *path[2];
        path[0] = "./tes";
        path[1] = NULL;

        dup2(fd, 1);
        dup2(fd, 2);
        close(fd);

        execve(path[0], (char **)&path, NULL);

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```